# WebAPI posting HTML entities cuts off parameters

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

I'm posting the contents of a div to the server like so.

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: self.settings.spellcheckURL,
    dataType: "json",
    data: "=" + content,
    processData: false,
    success: function(result) {
        ...
    }
});
```

and it works as expected, however when I have an html entity in my content such as `&nbsp;` I find that it is cut off in my Web API controller.

**Raw POST From Fiddler**

```
=<div>The <i><u>raaina&nbsp;</u></i>in <i><u>Spaaain </u></i><b><u>saatays</u> maaainly a</b>on the <u>plaains</u>..</div>
```

**Web API Controller**

[image]

What do I need to do to prevent this?

Comment: is that possiblity remove &nbsp; before passing data

Comment: try encoding might help you try as given in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to encode data before sending it , like this

```
var res = encodeURIComponent(uri);
```

your case

```
 data: "=" + encodeURIComponent(content)
```

[JavaScript encodeURIComponent() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp)